# ehcache Map<String,Entry> not work springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot, caching, ehcache

i tried to cache Map<String,Entry> , but every time i found getEntries() hit database without caching ,
also i serialize Entry object  , please yours support

```
@Cachable("stocks")
 public Map<String,Entry> getEntries(){
    //getting entry from database then convert to map
  return map;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me

```
@Service
public class OrderService {

    public static int counter = 0;

    @Cacheable("stocks")
    public Map<String, Entry> getEntries() {
        counter++;
        final Map<String, Entry> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("key", new Entry(123l, "interesting entry"));
        return map;
    }
}
```

Here's a test to prove the counter is not called.

```
   @Test
    public void entry() throws Exception {
        OrderService.counter = 0;
        orderService.getEntries();
        assertEquals(1, OrderService.counter);
        orderService.getEntries();
        assertEquals(1, OrderService.counter);
    }
```

I've added it all to my [github example](https://github.com/gregclinker/cache-example)